In TypeScript why does [1, 2] extend [...unknown[], 0, ...unknown[]]?
I'm trying to understand how infer in TypeScript conditional types work. One thing I've noticed about infer types in TypeScript is that they are defined to allow a rest element following another rest element. For example:
type A<T> = T extends [...infer X, 0, ...infer Y] ? [X, Y] : never;
type B = A<[1, 2]>; // B = [unknown[], unknown[]]

Interestingly, not only does TypeScript say this code is valid; the condition also succeeds, giving us X = unknown[] and Y = unknown[]. However, when we substitute in these inferred types, TypeScript gives us an error:
type C<T> = T extends [...unknown[], 0, ...unknown[]] ? true : false;
// Error: A rest element cannot follow another rest element. (1265)

Why does TypeScript require you to use infer when using multiple rest elements, and why does it say that the type [1, 2] contains the element 0?

Even though they don't throw an error in an extends clause, multiple rest types are not really supported. It is a known issue, currently considered a design limitation and unlikely to be fixed (emphasis mine):

This is unfortunately a design limitation as we have a very narrow heuristic that provides rudimentary support for inferring to multiple rest types in a tuple. It's not clear at this time whether this is something we want to extend. While a useful minimal repro, the example shown in the issue description doesn't illustrate a need that would be sufficient motivation to reevaluate this limitation. It would be helpful to understand the specific needs this issue is trying to address.


I'm surprised they don't give an error in all cases that this rudimentary support doesn't cover
